# Dictionary lookup - why use a hash table for fixed data?

Tags: c, dictionary, hashtable, lookup

In some (*horrible 3rd party*) code we're working with there is a dictionary lookup routine that scans through a table populated with "'name-string' -> function_pointer" pairs, basically copy-pasted from K&R Section 6.6.

I've had to extend this, and while reading the code was struck by the *seemingly* pointless inclusion of hashing routines that iterate through the source data structure and create a hash table.

Given that the source data structure is fixed at compile time (so will never be added to or changed when running), is there any point in having hashing routines in there?

I'm just having one of those moments when I can't tell if the author was doing something clever that I've missed, or was being lazy and not thinking (so far the latter has been the case more often than not).

Is there a reason to have a hash table for data that will never change?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reason to have a hash table for data that will never
>   change?

Probably the hash table code was already there and working fine, and the programmer just wanted to get the job done (e.g. looking up a function pointer from a string). If this function is not performance critical I see no reason to change it.

If you want to change it, then I suggest to take a look at perfect hash tables.

These are hash tables were the hash function is created from a fixed set of predefined keys. The good thing about them: They are often faster than a tree data-structure.

GPERF is a tool that does just this. It creates C-code from a set of strings: https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/